# Kubernetes - which pod receives request from load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a load balancer service for a deployment having 3 pods. When I do a rolling udpate(changing the image) by the following command :

> kubectl set image deployment/< deployment name > contname=< image-name >

and hit the service continuously, it gives a few connection refused in between. I want to check which pods it is related to. In other words, is it possible to see which request is served by which pods (without going inside the pods and checking the logs in them)? Also, Is this because of a race condition, as in when a pod might have got a request and had just been terminated before receiving that(almost simultaneously - resulting in no response)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you [configured liveness and readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) for you Pods? The service will not serve traffic to a Pod unless it thinks it is healthy, but without health checks it won't know for certain if it is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was looking at it. Could not understand the path parameter : < httpGet: path: /healthz >, should this be an endpoint of my service?

Comment: I tried this with my endpoints, but still I get a few requests reply as connection refused. I think liveness probe and readiness probe caters to when the pods are starting up not when they are going down, any idea if thats the case?

Comment: The `path: /healthz` is indeed supposed to be inside your service, but `path:` can be anything you want, as long as it resolves as 200.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand the second part! So, in < path: >can also be a command?

Comment: `path:` is a url inside your pods (in your application) that will return a [200 response](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) if the application is ready to handle traffic, this could just be `/`.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks a lot for the explaination.